# How to make a sub-dictionary from data of a line of a txt file?

Tags: python, list

I have this `.txt` file that needs to transformed into a dictorionary:
(the order of the lines may vary)

```
name : john doe
age : 23
gender : MALE
address : kendall 6, Miami
career: mechanical engineer
times going : 2
number of assignments : 4
semester : 4
average : 9.2
interests : gaming, robotics, drama movies
availability:
    friday : 6:30 - 10:30
    sunday : 12:30 - 13:30
    monday : 16:30 - 18:30
```

The output code should be like this:

```py
{'name': 'john doe',
 'age': '23',
 'gender': 'MALE',
 'address': 'kendall 6, Miami',
 'semester': '4',
 'career': 'mechanical engineer',
 'average': '9.2',
 'times going': '2',
 'number of assignments': '5',
 'interests': 'gaming, robotics, drama movies',
 'availability':
                {'friday': (630,1030),
                 'sunday': (1230,1330),
                 'monday': (1630,1830)
                 }
}
```

As for now, I have successfully made the dictionary just right before this "availability" section:

```py
dicc={}
listRestrictions=["availability","monday","tuesday","wednesday","thursday","friday","saturday","sunday"]

for line in file:
    line = line.strip("\n").replace(" : ", ":").strip(" ")
    key = line[: line.index(":")]
    if key not in listRestrictions:
        value = line[line.index(":") + 1 :]
        dicc[key] = value

print(dicc)
```

And prints:

```
{'name': 'john doe', 'age': '23', 'gender': 'MALE', 'address': 'kendall 6, Miami', 'career': 'mechanical engineer', 'times going': '2', 'number of assignments': '4', 'semester': '4', 'average': '9.2', 'interests': 'gaming, robotics, drama movies'}
```

*(keeping in mind it could be on any file of the `.txt` file and that the dates will always be under "availability")...*
How would I take the "availability" as the value and then the dates as sub-dictionary as shown above?

Comment: What's the file format?

Comment: I stated it is a .txt file.

Comment: Do you want the output availability times as integers?

Comment: That's not what I mean. Is it YAML? It does look like it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're trying such low level parsing. Isn't that YAML? That assumption gets me quite close:

```
import yaml
from pprint import pprint

with open('data.txt') as f:
    data = yaml.load(f)
```

Then `data` is this nested Python dictionary:

```
{'name': 'john doe',
 'age': 23,
 'gender': 'MALE',
 'address': 'kendall 6, Miami',
 'career': 'mechanical engineer',
 'times going': 2,
 'number of assignments': 4,
 'semester': 4,
 'average': 9.2,
 'interests': 'gaming, robotics, drama movies',
 'availability': {'friday': '6:30 - 10:30',
                  'sunday': '12:30 - 13:30',
                  'monday': '16:30 - 18:30'}}
```

The remaining differences are easy to do, now that it's a Python data structure.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to use any extra libraries other than OS and numpy. Thanks anyway, that looks like exactly what I need (but can't use ) :(

Answer (score 0):

```
dicc = {}
for line in file:
        isAppended = line.startswith("    ")
        line = line.strip("\n").replace(" : ", ":").strip(" ")
        value = line[line.index(":") + 1 :]
        tempKey = line[: line.index(":")]
        if len(value)==0:
            currKey = tempKey
            tempDict = {}
        elif isAppended:
            tempDict[tempKey] = value
            dicc.update({currKey:tempDict})
        else:
            dicc[tempKey] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    dicc={}

    last_key = ''

    for _line in file:

        line = _line.strip("\n").replace(" : ", ":")

        line = line.strip(" ")
        key = line[: line.index(":")]
        last_key = key
        value = line[line.index(":") + 1 :]
        if // the first part of the line is a blank space:
            dicc[last_key][key] = value
        else:
            dicc[key] = value

    print(dicc)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you pull your days and times, but assuming these are, for example, in the below format to begin with:

```
days = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday']
times = [(630, 1030), (830, 1400), (930, 1330)]
```

Then one way to build the availability dictionary is as follows:

```
dicc['availability'] = dict(zip(days, times))
print (dicc)
```

Comment: Looks like a rather cumbersome way to write `dict(zip(days, times))`...